# Is there an enroot equivalent to docker run?

Tags: docker, hpc

I have a simple container, that I've built with a Dockerfile.  I am running on `Ubuntu-20.04` with `enroot-3.4.1-1` and `Docker version 26.0.0`.

My `Dockerfile` takes a simple executable (compiled from C) and prints out 'Hello World', i.e. :

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM scratch
ADD hello /
CMD ["./hello"]
```

I can run this image :

```
root@head01:/home/user/Scratch# docker image ls
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
hello         latest    d08237299659   7 hours ago     872kB
.
.
.
root@head01:/home/user/Scratch# docker run hello
Hello World
```

I exported my `docker` image to a squashfs file via :

```
root@head01:~# mkdir dockerout
root@head01:~# docker export optimistic_almeida | tar -C dockerout -p -s --same-owner -xv    
root@head01:~# mksquashfs dockerout hello.sqsh
```

Now if I try to run this with `enroot`

```
root@head01:/home/user/Scratch# enroot start hello.sqsh
enroot-switchroot: failed to execute: /bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

Question :

1. Is there an `enroot` equivalent to `docker run` that just executes the `CMD` form the `Dockerfile`?  It seems like `enroot` wants an interactive session but I don't think I built in a shell for it.